# Calcular diferença entre datas e horas vindos do BD dos campos time e datas separados

Tags: data

Bom dia, 
Estou querendo criar um código onde possa informar a quantos dias e horas num intervalo de data, que sejam mostrados separadamente. tipo isso:

Hora inicio = 12:07:07 - 
Data Inicio = 15/10/2018 - 
Hora Final = 12:07:08 - 
Data Final = 16/10/2018 - 
**TEMPO = 24:00:01** - 
**TOTAL DE DIAS = 01**

Alguém pode me ajudar? Já tentei tudo que eu sabia, pesquise na internet e consegui adaptar para um código que mostrar apenas o intervalo de horas, mas queria melhorá-lo para mostrar o intervalo entre as datas também.

> segue o código abaixo

```
      $entrada = $row_pesquisar['horainicio'];
      $saida = $row_pesquisar['horafinal'];
      $row_pesquisar1['horainicio'] = explode(":",$entrada);
      $row_pesquisar1['horafinal'] = explode(":",$saida);
      $acumulador1 = ($row_pesquisar1['horainicio'][0] * 3600) + ($row_pesquisar1['horainicio'][1] * 60) + $row_pesquisar1['horainicio'][2];
      $acumulador2 = ($row_pesquisar1['horafinal'][0] * 3600) + ($row_pesquisar1['horafinal'][1] * 60) + $row_pesquisar1['horafinal'][2];
      $resultado = $acumulador2 - $acumulador1;
      $hora_ponto = floor($resultado / 3600);
      $resultado = $resultado - ($hora_ponto * 3600);
      $min_ponto = floor($resultado / 60);
      $resultado = $resultado - ($min_ponto * 60);
      $secs_ponto = $resultado; 
      $tempo = $hora_ponto.":".$min_ponto.":".$secs_ponto;
      echo $tempo;
```

Answer (score 0):

O código abaixo deve funcionar como você precisa:

```
<?php

    //Seta a data padrão pro php reconhecer o formato d/m/Y
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

    //Cria a data de inicio e fim convertendo a string em formato brasileiro pro formato americano
    $data_inicio = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('15-10-2018 12:07:07')));
    $data_final = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('16-10-2018 12:18:08')));

    //Pega a diferença das datas
    $diff = $data_final->diff($data_inicio);

    //Exibe resultado formatado

    echo $diff->format('TOTAL DE DIAS = %d');
    echo "<br>";

    //realiza o calculo pra pegar intervalo de horas
    echo "TEMPO = ". (($diff->d * 24) + $diff->h ) .':'. $diff->format('%i:%s');
```

Teste online: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/013b3cc9c3bb99d3ca089a989c66e846423c62a0

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
>   http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Bom dia Edson, eu tentei fazer com o modelo que me enviou, mas não consegui adaptar, o que eu tenho aqui é igual este que está no link abaixo, somente o o campo horas não é dividido da mesma forma: 
 https://www.horlogeparlante.com/calcular-as-dura%C3%A7%C3%B5es.html

Comment: Você pode concatenar a hora conforme precisar: `'15-10-2018' . $hora_inicio . ':'. $min_inicio . ':' . $seg_inicio`

Comment: Entendi, mas o meu caso é o seguinte, no BD tenho as colulas "horainicio, horafinal, created e modified", as colunas da hora  são do tipo time e as das datas são do tipo date apenas. Fiz assim pois tenho um formulário para mudar as informações assim que precisar, então será que tem como colocar $row_pesquisar['horainicio'] e $row_pesquisar['created'] dentro do mesmo $data_inicio = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime()?

Comment: Sim, pode testar... Basta concatenar os 2 separando por um espaço. `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', [...]` serve apenas para formatar a string no formato que o DateTime entende. Se já vem do banco neste formato nem precisa estar dentro. Basta chamar o DateTime direto passando a string

Comment: Edson fiz como me disse e como a data e o time ja vem formatado  banco, mas não funcionou, creio que eu esteja fazendo errado.    $data_inicio = (.$row_pesquisar['created'] .$row_pesquisar['horainicio']);
$data_final = (.$row_pesquisar['modified'] .$row_pesquisar['horafinal']);  ESSA É MENSAGEM DE ERRO Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\sistema-de-atendimento\relatorios.php on line 180

Comment: Tem um ponto no inicio da sua concatenação `$data_inicio = (. <-` e você precisa concatenar com um espaço assim: `$data_inicio = ($row_pesquisar['created'].' '.$row_pesquisar['horainicio']); `

Comment: Edson realmente era isso, mas esse trecho não está mostrando a hora  
    echo "TEMPO = ". (($diff->d * 24) + $diff->h ) .':'. $diff->format('%i:%s');  OLHA O CODIGO COMPLETO:          $data_inicio = ($row_pesquisar['created'].' '.$row_pesquisar['horainicio']);
$data_final = ($row_pesquisar['modified'].' '.$row_pesquisar['horafinal']);


   
    $diff = $data_final-$data_inicio;
   
    echo $diff;
    echo "<br>";
   
    echo "TEMPO = ". (($diff->d * 24) + $diff->h ) .':'. $diff->format('%i:%s');

Comment: $diff = `$data_final->diff($data_inicio);` Você tem que chamar a função e não subtrair um do outro. Subtraindo até da... Mas seria outro caso, vc teria que converter a data pra UNIX. Troca essa linha. E outra, você tem que criar o Datetime: `$data_inicio = new DateTime($row_pesquisar['modified'].' '.$row_pesquisar['horafinal'])`

Comment: Boa tarde Edson, eu até tinha colocado o DateTime, mas daí apareceu o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Call to undefined function DateTime() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\sistema-de-atendimento\relatorios.php on line 181, por isso que eu havia tirado, mas se tem que inserir, vou ver se consigo contornar esse erro.

Comment: DateTime é um objeto, para instancia-lo precisa colocar a palavra `new` antes

Comment: Edson, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado mesmo. Você é fera.

Comment: Opa que bom cara. Boa sorte ai

Comment: Edson bom dia, olha eu te incomodando novamente. Meu código ficou assim e está funcionando perfeitamente,           
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bahia');      
        $data_inicio = new DateTime($row_pesquisar['created'].' '.$row_pesquisar['horainicio']);
        $data_final = new DateTime($row_pesquisar['modified'].' '.$row_pesquisar['horafinal']);        
        $diff = $data_final->diff($data_inicio);   
mas seu eu quisesse contar somente os dias de segunda à sexta, teria como adaptar nesse mesmo código.

Comment: Putz, acho que teria que mudar toda a lógica mas nem sei como fazer... Cria outra pergunta especificamente sobre isto, o pessoal vai te ajudar.. não esquece de explicar bem e colocar seu código na pergunta. Sucesso

Comment: Muito obrigado Edson, você ja me ajudou muito.